# How to use Rolle's Theorem to prove this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f$ is a polynomial with $n$ distinct zeros, then $f'$ has at least
>   $n-1$ zeros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** By Rolle's Theorem, there is a zero of the derivative between any two (say consecutive) zeros of our function. We have $n$ distinct zeros, so $n-1$ "gaps."

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that the result depends on the polynomial being over the reals, so that you can use [Rolle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) as @AndréNicolas showed. For instance, for a prime $p$, the polynomial $x^{p^{n}} - x$ has $p^{n}$ distinct roots in $\operatorname{GF}(p^{n})$, but its derivative $-1$ has none.